How to poll/wait for queue submissions to finish with wgpu on WebGPU backend?
Lets take the following example:
fn job() {

let pipeline = ... a valid  *wgpu::ComputePipeline* 
let encoder = wgpu_device.create_command_encoder(&wgpu::CommandEncoderDescriptor {
            label: Some("encoder"),
        });
let mut cpass = encoder.begin_compute_pass(
            &wgpu::ComputePassDescriptor {
                label: Some("MyPass"),
                timestamp_writes: None,
            }
        );
cpass.set_pipeline(&pipeline);
cpass.dispatch_workgroups(size / 16 + 1, size / 16 + 1, 1);
drop(cpass);
wgpu_queue.submit(std::iter::once(encoder.finish()));
wgpu_device.poll(wgpu::Maintain::Wait);

}

Now from the docs, wgpu_device.poll(wgpu::Maintain::Wait); is essentially a No Op on WebGPU backend and when i time this bit of code as expected it becomes clear that the pass is working async.
My question is is there any way to actually block and wait here so that if i need to use the buffer's data for the next step(in a different pass in different part of code) i dont get wrong results.
The answer i am looking for would be either to wait for the pass here or atleast something like Memory barriers for the buffer.
